# How to convert dynamic JSON to C# object

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to convert below JSON object to C# class. I could able to get C# equivalent for **filter**, but not for **sort**.

In the case of **filter** JSON object; **andOr, openCondition,** etc are static. Hence, I could able to generate C# class.

But for **sort** JSON object; **accountName**, and **tradeDate** are not static. These fields are completely as per user requirement. They may change as some other fields for some other input. Hence, I'm not understanding how can I generate C# class for this **sort** JSON object. Can anyone please suggest me how to do this?

```
{
    "filter": [
        {
            "andOr": "",
            "openCondition": false,
            "columnName": "accountName",
            "operator": "eq",
            "value": "KATHERINE",
            "closeCondition": false
        }
    ],
    "sort": {
            "accountName": "asc",
            "tradeDate": "desc"       
    },
    "pageIndex": 1,
    "pageSize": 75
}
```

I have tried to create `SortCriteria` class like below. But, it is not matching to the JSON sort object.

```
public class SortCriteria
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest me how can I solve this issue.

Comment: That is why you have newtonsoft package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Dictionary` (with [JsonExtensionDataAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeExtensionData.htm)) for cases where properties are NOT fixed, such as in `Sort`. For example,

```
public class Filter
{
    public string andOr { get; set; }
    public bool openCondition { get; set; }
    public string columnName { get; set; }
    public string @operator { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public bool closeCondition { get; set; }
}

public class Sort
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string,object> RandomKeyValuePair {get;set;}
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Filter> filter { get; set; }
    public Sort sort { get; set; }
    public int pageIndex { get; set; }
    public int pageSize { get; set; }
}
```

**Sample Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your json properties are not fixed and it may change over the time then instead of creating a separate class you can use `dynamic`.

Like,

```
string jsonString = @"{
    sort: {
      accountName: 'asc',
      tradeDate: 'desc'       
    }
}";


JObject obj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
Console.WriteLine($"AccountNumber: {obj["sort"]["accountName"]}");
```

using Json path,

```
Console.WriteLine($"AccountNumber: {obj.SelectToken("$.sort.accountName")}");
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qKYMxZ)

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize any JSON object into a `Dictionary<string,object>` or if you know the value type you can use that value type instead of `object`.

In this case the sort value will only be `"asc"` or `"desc"` so we can use a `string` or (better) an `enum`

```cs
public enum SortDirection
{
    Asc,
    Desc,
}
```

The class would look like

```
public class Data
{
    ...
    [JsonProperty( "sort" )]
    public Dictionary<string,SortDirection> Sort { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

a minimal example

```cs
var json = "{\"sort\":{\"accountName\":\"asc\",\"tradeDate\":\"desc\"}}";
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```

[.net fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EznNpG)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. "Anu Viswan" answer worked well for me, hence, marked as accepted answer. Your suggestion is also valuable. Hence, given up-vote. I have not yet verified your suggestion, but looks like nice approach.

Comment: The verification is very simple: click on the .net fiddle link in the answer and see the working code sample in your browser ;o)